# Using Gradle wrapper (./gradlew.sh) with subprojects

Tags: gradle

I have a multi-project build with several sub projects and I want to use the gradle wrapper.

What's the idiomatic way to do this?

Should I configure the wrapper in every subproject by adding the following code to `build.gradle` in the root?

```
allprojects {
    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '2.2'
    }
}
```

But then, do I check all the `gradlew.bat`, `gradlew.sh`, `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar`, etc. files from *all* the subproject directories into version control??  That seems inefficient, but if I don't then how can I execute `./gradlew.sh` in a sub project directory?  What is the preferred way to use gradle wrapper in a subproject?

Do developers just use the gradle installed on the filesystem for this case?

The most important question is the first: what's the idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should just have the wrapper task outside of the allprojects block so you only have one `gradlew.bat`, `gradlew.sh`, and `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` at the top level of your project structure.

You can run the `./gradlew tasks --all` to verify the wrapper can see the subproject tasks

Or you can run the `./gradlew <subproject_name>:tasks` command to view just one subproject's tasks.

Comment: To be clear is this the idiomatic way to do this?  And is there an idiomatic solution to the problem of running a task with the wrapper while in a subproject directory?

Comment: To call the wrapped from the subproject directory, run ../gradlew

I'll defer to others to say whether this is the idiomatic way or not.  It is the way I do it at least.

Comment: This is the correct way. Additionally you can put a third-party `gradle(w)` script such as https://github.com/cbeams/dotfiles/blob/home/bin/gradle on your `PATH` that will search for the "real" `gradlew` script in parent directories. Then you can write `gradlew` instead of `./gradlew` or `../gradlew`.

Comment: But i run the script as you mentioned, the console show me : Task <sub_proj> not found in root project <root_proj>.

Comment: The `gradle(w)` script (mentioned by @PeterNiederwieser) has been removed, but I think I found the last version here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cbeams/dotfiles/164990d66a39c2aef6ab491837916fbddf515149/bin/gradle

Comment: Instead of using the mentioned gradle-script from GH I defined an alias for this: alias gradle="./gradlew" - If it doesn't find gradlew in the current dir it gives you an error message. If you want to use the "original" gradle use '\gradle <your task>'

Answer (score -1):

You may try this https://gng.dsun.org/. It will make you life easier with gradlew.